# Allocating a struct with void*

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, void-pointers

So let's say I have defined these structs:

```
typedef struct LRU {
    int i;
} LRU;

typedef struct WS {
    char i;
} WS;
```

and in my main I have defined a void pointer:

`void* mStruct = NULL;`

Depending on the case I need to use one of these structs so

```
if(!strcmp(algorithm, "LRU")) {
    mStruct = malloc(sizeof(LRU));
    mStruct->i = 1;
}
else if(!strcmp(algorithm, "WS")) {
    mStruct = malloc(sizeof(LRU));
}
else {
    printf("Unknown replacment algorithm %s\n", algorithm);
    return -1;
}

... // more code

free(mStruct);
```

But this line of code gives me an error: `mStruct->i = 1;`

So how do I access the struct and if this is not the ideal solution to my problem can you suggest the proper way of handling it?

Note that I don't want to declare a pointer to each struct (ex. `LRU *lruPtr;`)

Comment: in the first if shouldn't you use WS size `mStruct = malloc(sizeof(WS));` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a union instead:

```
union cache
{
    LRU lru;
    WS ws;
};

// ...

union cache *myCache = malloc(sizeof *myCache);
if(!strcmp(algorithm, "LRU")) {
    myCache->lru.i = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do something like that (you need to cast mStruct from `void*` to `LRU*`):

```
if(!strcmp(algorithm, "LRU")) {
    mStruct = malloc(sizeof(LRU));
    ((LRU*)mStruct)->i = 1;
}
```

But such code smells and using unions is a better option.